# New Silverlight features in 4.0

Tags: silverlight

For any silverlight fanatics out there, I was wanting to ask what type of new features does Silverlight 4.0 have compared to Silverlight 1.0 ? I am a Silverlight newbie and need to get that skillset accquired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [this table](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/overview.aspx) on the official site which compares every version of Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

Wow that is a loaded question.  I would suggest that you do some reading or watch some videos.  Here is a link to some Silverlight 4.0 videos that should get you going http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-4-videos/.  Silverlight has come a very long way since version 1.0.  I started with version 1.0 and its awesome to see how far the platform has come in such a short period of time.

Good luck and happy programming.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start at http://www.silverlight.net/

You'd also need to check out what was new in Silverlight 2 [(Dr Dobbs article)](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/207200289;jsessionid=ZZEOYSDTQZP2TQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN) and [Silverlight 3](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/silverlight3/) before checking out [what's new in Silverlight 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772166(VS.95).aspx) as each has built on the previous version